# i am getting invariant violation error in reactnative

Tags: react-native

i passing props and i used these props in my styling I am getting error
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the code so that we can check it? hard to try it out with a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From error I think that size is an object (because `"width": {}` and `"borderRadius": <<NaN>>`). Check all places where your component is used. Probably you are passing an object to it instead of a number

**UPD** It seems you forgot `{` and `}` around component parameters